# How to combine SELECT of reguler column with SELECT of SUM of the columns in one query?

Tags: mysql, select, sum

This is my query that does not work as intended:

```
SELECT `id`, SUM(`column1`) as `c1`, SUM(`column2`) AS `c2` 
FROM `table` 
WHERE `id` IN (18, 19, 20, 21)
```

What I'd like to get from it: I want to get `SUM(column1)` and `SUM(column2)` for every `id` listed in the `WHERE` part, and the "distinct" `id` that matches with it. I have no idea how to combine regular column SELECT with SUM column SELECT in one query - if it is even possible? Example:

```
`table` structure:
id column1 column2
18    5      3
18    5      3
20    10     10
20    10     5
20    10     5
21    1      1
22    10     10

Should return:
id  c1  c2
18  10  6
20  30  20
21  1   1
```

Comment: Ever heard of `GROUP BY`?

Comment: Well - nope, I wouldn't ask if I did, right? ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should group rows:

```
SELECT `id`, SUM(`column1`) as `c1`, SUM(`column2`) AS `c2` 
FROM `table` 
WHERE `id` IN (18, 19, 20, 21)
GROUP BY `id`
```

SUM, COUNT and other math functions works with GROUP BY.

If you need filter that special fields, use HAVING instead WHERE:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp